# Updatable tkinter canvas with mainloop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to be able to make my self a graphical api in Tkinter for a project
using **Python 2.7**

```py
import Tkinter as tk
# import tkinter as tk    # if you are using python 3


class Graphics(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, width=60, height=60, pixel_width=10):
        #super().__init__()
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.pixel_width = pixel_width
        # self.geometry(f'{self.width*self.pixel_width}x{self.height*self.pixel_width}')
        self.geometry('600x600')
        self.my_canvas = tk.Canvas(
            self, 
            width = self.width * self.pixel_width, 
            height = self.height * self.pixel_width,
        )

        self.pixels = [[None for x in range(self.width)] for y in range(self.height)]
        self.fill_area((0, 0), (self.width, self.height), 'white')

        self.fill_point((30, 30),'red')
        self.fill_area((10, 10), (15, 20), 'yellow')


        self.my_canvas.pack()
        self.run()

    def fill_point(self, point, color):
        pixel = self.pixels[point[0]][point[1]]
        if pixel is None:
            cx0 = self.pixel_width * point[0]
            cy0 = self.pixel_width * point[1]
            cx1 = self.pixel_width * (point[0] + 1)
            cy1 = self.pixel_width * (point[1] + 1)
            self.pixels[point[0]][point[1]] = self.my_canvas.create_rectangle(cx0, cy0, cx1, cy1, fill=color)   # outline=''
        else:
            self.my_canvas.itemconfig(pixel, fill=color)

    def fill_area(self, pointA, pointB, color):
        for x in range(pointA[0], pointB[0]):
            for y in range(pointA[1], pointB[1]):
                self.fill_point((x, y), color)

    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()


g = Graphics()
g.fill_point((9,9),'blue')
```

As I've understood the `mainloop` method is blocking any further actions on the canvas and I need a solution for an updatable screen.

I tried using threads with `mainloop` and `update` methods but it would just immediately exit the window.

**Thank you for helping and have a nice day**

Comment: You must use tkinter's widget.after function. Just place `self.myCanvas.after(delay_here, update)` after your first update.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to read a little bit about the tkinter canvas, and its immense capabilities: unlike pygame, or other graphics canvasses, it does not need to refresh at a given frequency; canvas items can be addressed individually, and their attributes set precisely.

I reworked your code to display a canvas made of 'scaled pixels': here 60 x 60 pixels wide, with each pixels scaled up by a factor 10.
The 2D list `self.pixels` contains canvas items; the updates directly change the attributes of these items.

You can remove the black lines around each pixel by setting their attribute `outline` to the empty string (see comment in the code).

```
import Tkinter as tk
# import tkinter as tk    # if you are using python 3


class Graphics(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, width=60, height=60, pixel_width=10):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.pixel_width = pixel_width
        # self.geometry(f'{self.width*self.pixel_width}x{self.height*self.pixel_width}')
        self.geometry('600x600')
        self.my_canvas = tk.Canvas(
            self, 
            width = self.width * self.pixel_width, 
            height = self.height * self.pixel_width,
        )

        self.pixels = [[None for x in range(self.width)] for y in range(self.height)]
        self.fill_area((0, 0), (self.width, self.height), 'white')

        self.fill_point((30, 30),'red')
        self.fill_area((10, 10), (15, 20), 'yellow')


        self.my_canvas.pack()
        self.run()

    def fill_point(self, point, color):
        pixel = self.pixels[point[0]][point[1]]
        if pixel is None:
            cx0 = self.pixel_width * point[0]
            cy0 = self.pixel_width * point[1]
            cx1 = self.pixel_width * (point[0] + 1)
            cy1 = self.pixel_width * (point[1] + 1)
            self.pixels[point[0]][point[1]] = self.my_canvas.create_rectangle(cx0, cy0, cx1, cy1, fill=color)   # outline=''
        else:
            self.my_canvas.itemconfig(pixel, fill=color)

    def fill_area(self, pointA, pointB, color):
        for x in range(pointA[0], pointB[0]):
            for y in range(pointA[1], pointB[1]):
                self.fill_point((x, y), color)

    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()


g = Graphics()
```

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks a lot.
I'm not that familiar with oop in python 2.7 as I come from c#
your code doesn't work for me in python 2.7..

I get problems in the `super` method and in the `geometry` variable..

Comment: ah, shoot, sorry! Indeed f strings and super are different in py2; I modified it, it should work now, but I don't have access to a py2 interpreter to try. Let me know if you still have a problem.

Comment: the first line of the constructor doesn't work as well the super.__init__() thingy

Comment: please look at my updated code.. I want to color a point mid run (my intention is making a game in this screen) Why isn't it working